# Reading URL content using Apache httpclient in Java 1.4

Tags: java, timeout, httpconnection

In Java 1.4, I am trying to make an connection to a URL, but since I want to configure a timeout, I am using Apache's httpclient instead of the old school URLConnection.openConnection();

So I have the following:

```
    HttpConnection conn = null;
    SimpleHttpConnectionManager httpMgr = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager(true);
    HostConfiguration hostConf = new HostConfiguration();
    hostConf.setHost(new HttpHost("http://www.google.com"));
    conn = httpMgr.getConnectionWithTimeout(hostConf, 30);
    conn.open();
```

But seems like everytime I try to open a connection, I would get a java.net.UnknownHostException: http://www.google.com, even to google.com.

Did I do something wrong..?

Comment: Unrelated, but why java 6 will be EOL in February.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm stuck with Java 1.4

Comment: Are you trying to run the code behind a firewall? If so, your question is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/6384135/130224

Answer (score 2):

I think protocol (http://) is what breaks it. Try using "www.google.com" as a host name. 
HTTP CLient tutorial is [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html).

Comment: Oh great now it works!  But somehow, after the connection gets opened, it fails to retrieve the input stream conn.getResponseInputstream()